# Removing words from FastText Model / Converting a .vec file to a .bin file (vec2bin)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, fasttext

I am working with FastText on a language (Tamil) and a task where I don't expect to encounter and simply don't care about character/words from other languages. I have both the text (`.vec`) and binary (`.bin`) files for this model. **I want to know how to either:**

**1. Remove words from the vocabulary of the model** (after loading it from the `.bin` file), and then save it to disk as `.bin` (I know how to do the saving, but not if/how I can delete words from its vocab).

**2. Convert the `.vec` file to a `.bin` file** (this way, I can use simple text processing to drop the unnecesary rows).

Some context: The model files are huge, and the main operation I am interested in (computing vector similarity/finding nearest vectors) takes far too long, and sometimes consumes all of my RAM altogether (admittedly there are other concurrent memory-intensive processes). Doing some cursory text munging/regex matching/line counting in the Terminal, I know that I could **massively** shrink the model if I dropped all words in its vocabulary that simply aren't relevant to my task, viz, those which contains characters outside (1) the Tamil Unicode block and (2) outside ASCII 0-40 (numbers/punctuation/common translingual ASCII symbols).

Is there a way to do (1) or (2) above, or, if not, is there some other way to accomplish my end goals here? I am aware of quantizing but am treating it as a last resort; given the non-Tamil words are nothing but pure bloat given the nature of my project, it seems silly to engage in lossy compression when I could "losslessly" compress by deleting the cruft.

Comment: Where'd the model come from, that it has so many irrelevant words or nonword tokens? Are you hoping to retain the Fasttext ability to synthesize guess-vectors for unknown words (which would be lost if subsetting just the `.vec` file of known full words), or happy with just the fixed set of good words you choose? How many full known words are in the model to start, & how many do you expect will remain after dropping those you don't want?

Comment: @gojomo It's the Tamil model from FastText. It's got 2 million words, of which ~15% (~300K) contain characters I don't care about. I am interested in retaining that ability, but only for words with the characters I care about (Tamil + symbols/numbers).

Comment: Gotcha. So, discarding *some* words from a plain set of full-word vectors isn't that hard. But discarding only 15% of the words will only be a modest ~15% loaded-model savings - from the plain vector overhead. And, if you're retaining the 'subword' info in a ful binary FT model for OOV vector synthesis, then (a) there's no easy way to back-out just the unwanted subwords; (b) the full collision-oblivious lookup-table of all subwords remains at full size - I think that's still 2M full-width vectors per FT defaults (which I think the pretrained models use).

Comment: So from full model, if (as rough guess) loading takes 8GB RAM, discarding 15% of the full-words is only going to shrink the loaded model by ~7% – to ~7.44GB RAM. Not sure that will really "move the needle" on your bottlenecks. Note that mere lookup-most-similars only searches among known full-words, so if that's a distinct/separately-batchable function, maybe you can do that just against the (~4GB * 0.85% shrink) ~3.4GB full-words, & do any OOV-lookups on some process distinct by time/system?

Comment: Or, maybe something else (multiprocessing? other inefficiencies) blows peak RAM needs up in way that, if fixed/optimized, could free more RAM than the meager ~560MB from 15% word-discards? You really do want such a model to be completely in RAM, with no risk of virtual-mem swapping - so much so that surge-renting larger machines often more efficient than ekeing a bit more headroom out with fragile workarounds.

Comment: @gojomo that's not true that "lookup-most-similars only searches among known full-words." I just tried it, definitely works for OOV as long as at least one subword is in the vocab.

Comment: Wait, I don't follow your math. 15% of 8 is 1.2, leaving 6.8— where did you get 7%/7.4GB from?

Comment: Should have been clearer: the *results* are only from known words. But yes, you can specify an OOV word as the origin/query, & it will synthesize for you. But: depending on your workflow, you could conceivably synthesize all needed OOV word vectors in a batch - an op that requires *no* known words in memory, so could theoretically be done with a ~half size model. Then, when looking up similars, drop the OOV functionality & use the precalced OOV vectors as queries - needing only the known words – again ~half the model.

Comment: Discarding the 15% of words only saves you model size from the ~half of the model devoted to the 2M known words - in really really rough terms, from ~4GB of a  ~8GB model, ergo, ~7.5% of full model. The other ~4GB is 2M subword vectors, which can't meaningfully be trimmed incrementally.

Comment: That model has 300d vectors, right? So while the known-word-vectors & subword-vectors are the largest parts, they're actually 2M*300d*4bytes/float=2.4GB each. So however larger it is in RAM upon load now, dropping 15% of all known words only saves  ~360MB of vectors, & maybe a few more tens of MB of the token->vector slot dict. Far fron 15% of total load size.